# Laravel attach with extra field

Tags: laravel, pivot

I have 3 tables, *products*, *images* and *product_image*. The 3rd one is a pivoting table. Other than *product_id* and *image_id* in *product_image* table, I also have 2 extra fields in this pivoting table: *position* and *type*, now for an existing *product* model A, how do I attach an image to A and at the same time set up its *position* and *type* value in that pivoting record? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```php
$product = Product::find(1);
// if you need also to save the image
$image = new Image(array('foo' => 'bar'));
$product->images()->save($image,array('position'=>'foo', 'type'=>'bar' ));
// if you know image id
$product->images()->attach([$imageId => ['position'=>'foo', 'type'=>'bar']]);
```

Comment: The following worked for me in laravel 5
$table1->relation()->attach($attributes['array_field'], ["field"=>$attributes["field"]]);

Comment: Jamal Abdul Nasir's comment worked for me in L5.4. Why haven't I found it on the docs though :(

Answer (score 2):

You need just add a array to attach method as second  parameter

```
//for example:    
$product->images()->attach($newImage, ['foo'=>'bar']);
```

It is more eloquent solution.